# Maven password protected repository and missing artifacts

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to use a password protected Artifactory repository for my Maven projects, but I am having no luck getting maven to retrieve the artifacts from the repository.  I have gone through the steps at http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html to set up an encrypted password for the Artifactory server. I first ran the command:

```
mvn --encrypt-master-password <password>
```

to encrypt the master password, and I put the result in .m2/settings-security.xml like so:

```
<settingsSecurity>
    <master>{encrypted password here}</master>
</settingsSecurity>
```

I then ran the command:

```
mvn --encrypt-password <password>
```

to encrypt the password that is used to access my Artifactory repository.  With the returned encrypted password, I made a new `<server>` entry in .m2/settings.xml like so:

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>repository-id</id>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password>{pIpgu5+61kYHmlKWza1Vy4f8m0UmlEa6P0TYbKoC5ac=}</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

So according to the tutorial, that is all there is to it, but whenever I try to reference the repository in my pom.xml, all the artifacts cannot be found even though they are correct in the pom.xml. Here is a snippet from my pom.xml (an example) that is not working like it should.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repository-id</id>
        <name>repository name</name>
        <url>my repository url</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group-id</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact-id</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The (theoretical) dependency 'group-id' is never found even though it exists at the repository I specified. both the repository and dependency elements are correct. The `<id>` of the repository is the same as the `<id>` of the server I specified in settings.xml

This makes no sense to me, and I have not found any hints as to what I need to do to use a repository with an encrypted password in my pom.xml. Is this all I need to do? if so, why is it not finding the artifacts? 
thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you verified that the host machine can see the repository via http?

Comment: Yes I can connect to the repo, and I am not behind a proxy.

Comment: is this dependency a lib or a plugin? you might need a pluginRepository instead of a normal one. also - is it a snapshot?. lastly - have you tried dropping the password encryption and just specifying the password in plain text in the settings? have you tried explicitly telling maven where the settings file is (-S flag), maybe its not looking where you think it is.

also, run maven with the -X and -U flags. the 1st is for more info, the 2nd is to prevent any caching/retry issues

Comment: Which maven version do you use?